# Android: loading a map that doesn't lose quality while zooming in

Tags: android, dictionary, imageview

I'd like to have a map in my activity where it's possible to drag and zoom in.
When zooming in, the quality of the image goes down, so i tried putting an image with 
a higher resolution in my drawable folders.

The problem is that I get a outofmemory error now.

What should i do?

Comment: How far are you zooming in? Google Map API is pretty standard for Map apps, I have never heard of anyone needing to load separate high res images due to poor resolution on zoom.

Comment: i'm zooming in 8 times. Also, it's a custom map for a amusement park, not a google maps kind of map.

Comment: the quality also escalates very fast, even when zooming in 4 times or so

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Skobbler maps by Scout. They are in vector, so you will have beautiful performance, and they also have some opportunities, that Google Maps haven't (routing, navigation, real reach, positioning, etc). http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/android